# Recommending similar products for customers on an e-commerece website

Tags: vb.net

I have created an e-commerce website which sells ebooks, it has a catalogue and shopping cart for my products which works just fine. I now want to be able to give recommendations for a similar product when the user adds something to a cart but I am not sure how to go about doing this. I was thinking to check what is inside the cart and then check which category it falls under and then display on the side products from the same category for the shopper. but I don't know how to do this.
For example, if a customer selects a maths textbook and clicks on "add to cart" then the program should display more maths textbook on the side.

I tried this which does not work...

```
Dim connection As SqlConnection
Dim mathcommand As SqlCommand
Dim sqlString As String
Dim rdr As SqlDataReader
sqlString = ("SELECT * FROM books WHERE Subject='Mathematics'")
mathcommand = New SqlCommand(sqlString)
If Session("cart") Is sqlString Then


    connection = New SqlConnection(" Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ebooksshelve.mdf;Integrated Security=True")


    mathcommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    mathcommand.Connection = connection
    mathcommand.Connection.Open()
    mathcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    rdr = mathcommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)



    Dim bookinfo As String = " "
    If rdr.HasRows Then
        bookinfo &= "<table class ='table' border='8'>"
        Do While rdr.Read
            Dim book As String = "<tr>"

            book &= "<tr>" _
               & "<td><ul>" _
                           & "<font size='5'><b> <a href='ProductDescription.aspx?prodID=" & rdr("Id") & "' >" & rdr("Name") & "</a></b></font>" _
                            & "<li><b>ISBN: " & rdr("ISBN") & "</b></li>" _
                            & "<li><b>Name: " & rdr("Name") & "</b></li>" _
                            & "<li><b>Author: " & rdr("Author") & "</b></li>" _
                            & "<li><b>Price: R " & rdr("Price") & "</b></li>" _
                            & "<li><b>Subject: " & rdr("Subject") & "</b></li>" _
                               & "</ul></td>" _
                            & "<td> <img src= '" & rdr("Image") & "' width=175 height=175/></td>"
            book &= "</tr>"
            bookinfo &= book

        Loop
        bookinfo &= "</table>"

    End If

    mathcommand.Connection.Close()
    mathcommand.Dispose()
    connection.Dispose()
End If
```

Comment: Explain what you mean by it doesn't work. You are concatenating two <tr>s in a row. Don't use font tags. Learn string.format and stringbuilder.

Answer (score 0):

you also need to improve your query:

SELECT * FROM books WHERE Subject='Mathematics' AND ID <> PRODUCTID(Selected Product Id)

its better not to show already selected product again in similar products